# Show that convolution product $f*g\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ if $f,g\in L^{1}$ and$g\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}.$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-transform, convolution

Show that convolution product $f*g$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ if $f,g\in L^{1}$ with $g\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}.$

My attempt: First observe that, since $f*g=g*f$ we have that,
$$(f*g)(x) = \int f(x-y)g(y)dy$$
and so,
$$(f*g)'= (f*g').$$
Now we have to justify why $F(x) = (f*g')(x)$ is continuous. For this we look at the difference,
\begin{align*}
|F(x)-F(y)|\leq \int |f(t)|\cdot |g'(x-t) - g'(y-t)|dt\leq \epsilon ||f||_1
\end{align*}
where given $\epsilon>0$ we found a $\delta>0$ such that,
$$|x-y|<\delta \implies |g'(x-t)-g'(y-t)|<\epsilon.$$ So we use the the same $\delta$ for showing the continuity of $F.$ Now we just apply this argument repeatedly to get that $f*g$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}.$ I don't know if this argument is correct so any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: $f*g(x) = \int f(y)g(x-y)dy$ also. So you can get the derivatives by moving the derivative inside the integral. One idea is to use dominated convergence theorem for it

Comment: Moving the derivative inside gives me $f*g'.$ Is this correct?

Comment: yes. by the way if it is differentiable it is automatically continuous

Comment: Yes you are right. So I guess pushing the derivative inside needs justification and that can be done using the dominated convergence theorem, right?

Comment: thats right buddy!

Comment: Well, you cannot simply use the dominated convergence theorem, since it's assumptions will not be satisfied. I don't think your claim is true. In addition to $g \in C^\infty$, you will need some assumption on the derivatives of $g$, like $\|\partial^\alpha g\|_{L^\infty} < \infty$, or something.